# Proving that $T$ is a unitary endomorphism of $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

For each orthonormal basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$, show that the map $T : \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ defined by $Tv = (\langle v, e_1 \rangle, \dots, \langle v, e_n \rangle)$ is a unitary endomorphism.

Hint: Use the formula $\| v\|^2 =  \sum_{k=1}^n | \langle v, e_k \rangle |^2$.

---

I'm guessing that we prove it by showing $\|Tv\| = \|v\|$ but I'm not sure how to get there. I'm particularly confused because the previous examples only use the (conjugate) linearity of the inner product and the definition of orthonormality to easily simplify the expression (e.g. $\langle v, e_k \rangle = c_k$ where $v = \sum c_j v_j$), but I'm not sure what to do when we are given $Tv$ in the form of an n-tuple of complex numbers.

EDIT: The inner product is arbitrary, as well as the orthonormal basis.

edit: One of my biggest confusions is the relation of the n-tuple given as the definition of $Tv$ to other vectors in $C^n$ that we have encountered previously, e.g. the $e_k$. I just don't understand how to reconcile the two different notations, despite them being the same algebraic structure.

Comment: Just compute $\|Tv\|^2$ and use the formula. Doesn't that work?

Comment: @equin yeah I don't know how one woudl compute $\langle Tv, e_k \rangle$. that's my confusion essentially.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well that's just the $k$-th component of the vector $Tv$. In other words: $\langle Tv, e_k \rangle = \langle v , e_k \rangle$. In general, for a vector $v = (v_1,...,v_n) = v_1 e_1 + ... + v_n e_n$ we get $\langle v, e_k \rangle = v_k$.

Comment: It might help to give the standard basis of $\Bbb C^n$ a name, e.g. $f_1,\dots,f_n$. Then you can express $Tv = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v, e_i\rangle f_i$.

Comment: @BrentKerby that's what I was thinking, but didn't know if that was justified.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I didn't see that we were working with an arbitrary orthonormal basis. I thought it was just the standard one. My bad. I guess another approach would be to apply a change of coordinates (changes of coordinates between orthonormal basis are unitary if I remember correctly), and then work in the standard basis.

Comment: Is $\left \langle / \right \rangle$ an arbitrary inner product, or the standard one?

Comment: @Reveillark it is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

The property $\left \| Tv \right \|= \left \| v \right \|$ obviously works considering the standard basis and inner product (and hence the Euclidean norm), but I don't think it does with an arbitrary inner product.

Put $B=\left \{ (1,1),(1,2) \right \}$, obviously $B$ is a basis for $\mathbb{C} ^2$. Note that:

$$(x,y)=(2x-y)(1,1)+(y-x)(1,2)$$

Define: $$\left \langle (x,y) / (a,b) \right \rangle = (2x-y)\overline{2a-b} + (y-x)\overline{b-a}$$

It is easy to verify that this constitutes an inner product in $\Bbb{C}^2$ and that $B$ is orthonormal with respect to this inner product.

Note that $\left \langle (6,4)/(6,4) \right \rangle = (12-4)^2 + (4-6)^2 = 68$ , and therefore $\left \| (6,4) \right \| = \sqrt{68}$

Now $T(6,4)=\left ( \left \langle (6,4)/(1,1) \right \rangle , \left \langle (6,4),/1,2) \right \rangle \right )=(8,-2)$

Therefore $$\left \langle T(6,4) / T(6,4) \right \rangle  = (16-(-2))^2 + (-2-8)^2 = 424$$

Hence $\left \| T(6,4) \right \| = \sqrt{424}\neq \sqrt{68}=\left \| (6,4) \right \|$

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is the euclidean inner product then. I'm in a class where the professor types us his own notes. While very convenient, it does have the downfall of not being proofread hundreds of times over, which may result in unclear wording. In particular, the entirety of this section deals with an arbitrary inner product, so it would be unexpected that it now deals with the standard inner product, which is why I assumed it would be arbitrary.